# Make one defined category secure

Tags: secure

How can I force one defined category page to use https secure instead of using unsecre url.

I am using Magento Version 1.6.2.0

Thanks for help.

Comment: Is there a reason for not setting all pages secure?

Comment: That's a customer requirement...

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a (configurable) solution inside Magento so I suggest making use of webserver redirection.

If there is no access to the virtual host configuration, use rewrites ([`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/path/to/category\.html$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Otherwise you can redirect using [`mod_alias`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # …
    RedirectMatch "^/path/to/category\.html$" "https://www.yoursite.com/path/to/category.html"
    # …
</VirtualHost >
```

Note: These patterns/expressions above may require some adjustments based on your specific situation.